# mySQL statement ORDER BY multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

If I have two columns, prices (full_price, sales_price), and these columns has numbers in them. I know that sql statements can do multiple order by's but how does it work when these columns have values in them?

```
("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY full_price,sales_price DESC")
```

How do I accomplish so it will pick the smallest value of the two columns? and it will place the data in order based on the chosen column between full_price and sales_price?

Note: sometimes sales_price will have no value.

Thanks

Edit:

Example

```
id    full_price        sales_price
1      23                 42           
2      342                200
3      1
4      10                 8
```

What I'm trying to do is with these numbers, I can output data associated with the lowest price.

The order should be:

```
3,4,1,2
```

Reason:

```
3: 1
4: 8
1: 23
2: 200
```

Comment: I edited to show an example, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that your blank `sales_price` is a NULL and that `full_price` cannot be NULL:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
order by case
    when sales_price is null then full_price
    else least(full_price, sales_price)
end
```

You probably want to add a secondary sort key to get consistent and sensible results from ties.

Comment: how would i add another sort key? do i add it into the case or is it after the end?

Comment: @andrewliu: You'd add the second sort key after then `end`: `order by case ... end, some_other_column`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY case when sales_price is null or full_price is null
              then 0
              when full_price > sales_price
              then sales_price ASC
              else full_price ASC
         end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want results based on difference of full_price and sales_price then try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY ABS(full_price - IF(sales_price IS NULL, 0, sales_price)) ASC
```

or if you want results based on comparision of full_price and sales_price then try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY IF(full_price < IF(sales_price IS NULL, 0, sales_price), 
            full_price , sales_price ) ASC
```